# Longest Common Increasing Subsequence Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm working on finding a solution to the longest common increasing sub sequence problem. Here's a link if you're not familiar with it. [LCIS](http://poj.org/problem?id=2127)

The problem can basically be reduced to two different problems. 'Longest common subsequence' and 'Longest increasing subsequence'. Here's the recursive solution to Longest common subsequence:

```
LCS(S,n,T,m)
{
if (n==0 || m==0) return 0;
if (S[n] == T[m]) result = 1 + LCS(S,n-1,T,m-1); // no harm in matching up
else result = max( LCS(S,n-1,T,m), LCS(S,n,T,m-1) );
return result;
}
```

Based on that and the general recursive formula found [here](http://hoverbear.org/2014/11/15/lcis/) I've been trying to implement the algorithm so I can use dynamic programming.

```
int lcis(int S[4], int n, int T[4], int m, int prev)
{
  int result;

  if (n == 0 || m  == 0)
    return 1;
  if (S[n] == T[m] && S[n] > S[prev]){
    result = myMax(1 + lcis(S, n-1, T, m-1, n), lcis(S, n-1, T, m, prev),
                    lcis(S, n, T, m-1, prev)) ;
  }
  else
    result = max(lcis(S,n-1,T,m, prev), lcis(S,n,T,m-1, prev));

  return result;
}
```

Obviously this does not give the correct solution. Any help would be appreciated.

For example, if I give it the two sequences {1, 2, 4, 5} and {12, 1, 2, 4} I get an output of 2. The correct output here would be 3, for the sub sequence {1,2,4}

EDIT:

Here is some revised code, after suggestions from below. Still not 100% correct. But closer. Note I am now using vectors, but this shouldn't change anything.

```
int lcis(vector<int> S, int n, vector<int> T, int m, int size)
{
  int result;

  if (n < 0 || m < 0)
    return 0;
  if (S[n] == T[m] && (n == size - 1 || S[n] < S[n + 1] )){
    result = myMax(1 + lcis(S, n - 1, T, m - 1, size), lcis(S, n - 1, T, m, size),
                    lcis(S, n, T, m - 1, size));
  }
  else
    result = max(lcis(S, n-1, T, m, size), lcis(S, n, T, m-1, size));

  return result;
}
```

Comment: _"Obviously this does not give the correct solution"_.  No, it's not obvious at all.  You have not shown input or expected _vs_ actual output.  If you want help, don't expect us to go off and follow web links to understand the problem and then try to match it to your algorithm, then try to figure out what input you've given it.

Comment: In some cases, e.g. when starting or restarting, there is no `prev`.

Comment: @paddy I have updated my post with an example input and output.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you are going backward through the array. So this test

```
 S[n] > S[prev]
```

Should be the other way around:

```
 S[n] < S[prev]
```

I am not sure why you need prev at all, as it should always be n+1, so maybe use

```
if (S[n] == T[m] && n < 3 && S[n] < S[n+1])
```

If you need to make it work for any size, then either pass the size in, or just a flag to say don't check n+1

Edit:

My mistake - you want to be going through the first if case when `n == 3` (or size), as you are at the start of a (potentially) increasing subsequence.

The if test should be

```
if (S[n] == T[m] && (n == 3 || S[n] < S[n+1]))
```

Note that this if test:

```
if (n == 0 || m  == 0)
    return 1;
```

is ignoring the first element of either sequence (and assuming it is at the end of an increasing subsequence). What is needed is to stop the recursion when you have gone before the start of either sequence. You also know that when you have gone before the start of the sequence, you can't possibly be in a subsequence, so you can return 0 for the length of the subsequence. So the test should be

```
if (n < 0 || m < 0)
    return 0;
```

Comment: Wow you're so right about the prev variable, I was over thinking it. Your suggestion seems to work. Just to clarify, I would check for n < size?

Comment: Another consideration: would this solution work if the sequences are of different size?

Comment: n < size should work fine. I think the idea should work for sequences of different sizes as you recurse through every option. However,  I think you have a problem with your end condition, if both sequences are the same, I think you end up with size + 1 (maybe test a few more sequences).

Comment: Hmm you seem to be right. After testing, now matter which two sequences I give it, if they are the same, the output is two. I'm still failing to see how my end condition is causing this. Can you clarify what you mean by you end up with size + 1? Thanks

Comment: Oops - I meant size - 1 (i.e. 3 for both sequences being 1,2,3,4). I'll update my answer with some new info.

Comment: I see the logic behind both of your proposed changes. However, after implementing them, I end up with the same behavior, an output of 2. Odd. Regarding the {1, 2, 3, 4} example, when you say n==3, wouldn't that be n==size - 1? I have updated the question with my most recent code if you want to look.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't changed my code to have a size parameter - it should be `n == size -1`. In your code you just posted you check for `n == size` which will never be true. Also you need to do the check for `n == size - 1` *before* you try to access `S[n+1]` otherwise you have an out-of-bound array access.

Comment: You're right, I actually tested it on both sides of the || but didn't consider that. Anyways, after implementing those changes I still get the output of 2. I'm stumped. Probably missing something simple. I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: have you tried implementing this by chance? Just curious if it's an error in my implementation or the algorithm. After looking at it more the algorithm appears to be sound.

Comment: Yes, I did. I think I only changed the two lines above, added main to call it and wrote a `myMax` function. I guess it is possible that your myMax is wrong. Another thing I did is to output `n`, `m`, and `result` just before the final return statement in lcis. I also recommend running it through a debugger, so you can track what is going on.